# Distribution of the local time for reflected Brownian motion on the quadrant

Tags: probability-distributions

If $W$ and $B$ are two independent Brownian motions, $X_t=W_t-\sup_{u\le t} B_u + 1$. I want to find the distribution of $S$ the first hitting time of $0$ by $X$. If someone could give me a direction to follow I would be grateful. I have no idea how to start the problem.